# Lock screen during async task execution

Tags: android

I want to lock the screen of the phone or tablet while an async task is executing.
for android version 2.3 i've used an progress dialog to do that,but on android version 4.1 it doesn't seem to work(if i touch the screen during the execution of an async task,the progress dialog will go in background ).The execution of the async task will continue in the background but this can confuse the user because you cannot see what is happening until the execution of the async task is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your dialog not cancelable from touching the outside of the `ProgressDialog`.

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

See: [Dialog Javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29)